# How can I separate ActiveAdmin controller into new file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

My `controller do` block in a registered ActiveAdmin model is starting to look big now so I would like to put the controller part in some other file.

Is that possible? What should be the new file's name and path?

Thank you

Comment: Checkout [this](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3673) issue, specifically, Sam's solution. You can use a controller concern and include it in your registered resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great question and unfortunately there is no great answer. I tend to push everything else into separate files, first the views using partials...

```
show title: 'Order' do
  render 'show', context: self
end

form partial: 'form'
```

...then the [business logic using services](http://reverbhq.com/blog/2012/08/building-web-apps-with-activeadmin/).  It is possible to extract controller methods using ActiveSupport::Concern, and [ActiveAdmin does this internally](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/lib/active_admin/resource_controller.rb) but I don't find it satisfying. Maybe one day we'll have a pull request to reference a user supplied subclass of ResourceController but it hasn't happened yet. TL;DR [use Concerns](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/3673#issuecomment-72731951) if extracting partials and Services are not enough.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. I was hoping there was a way to extract the controller part because not everything is business logic, there is a lot of flashing errors, handling the params, etc, but I'll just move the views out of the file with partials.