# Reducing line count of calls to ActiveAdmin.register by using helper methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I want to reduce the line count of my calls to `ActiveAdmin.register` by using semantically-relevant helper methods in order to improve readability. Overall, I'm less interested in testability and more focused on SRP.

Effectively, what I'm trying to accomplish is this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  include ActiveAdmin::RegisterHelpers::User
  # code
end
```

Ruby isn't too keen on allowing a module inclusion within a block.

To give the layout of the land, my resource presently looks something like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  # config stuff ==========
  config.batch_actions = false
  config.comments = true
  # more config things

  # params stuff ==========
  permit_params :name, 
    :birthdate,
    :favorite_color,
    # 30 other parameters

  # filter stuff ==========
  preserve_default_filters
  filter :thing, as: :select, collection: MyThings.options
  filter :other_thing, as: :select, collection: MyOtherThings.options
  # 10 other filters

  # form stuff ==========
  form do |f|
    f.input :name
    f.input :thing
    f.input :other_thing
    # 17 other inputs
  end

  # action_item stuff ==========
  action_item :toggle_thing, only: :show do
    # view code
  end

  # action stuff ==========
  index do
     # ...
  end
  show do
     # ...
  end
  # more actions

  # member_action stuff ==========
  member_action :toggle_status, method: :post do
    # action code
  end
  member_action :do_other_thing, method: post do
    # action code
  end

  # controller stuff ==========
  controller do
    # ...
  end
end
```

In my ideal world, each one of these "stuff" sections would be handled by its own helper method, like so:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  register_config
  register_params
  register_filters
  register_form
  register_action_items
  register_actions
  register_member_actions
  register_controller
end
```

There would then be a helper module nearby with each of these methods defined:

```
module ActiveAdmin::UserHelper
  def register_config
    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

I've investigated using `ActiveAdmin::ViewHelpers` and I have a couple of issues with these:

1. It seems that they cannot be called directly from `#register` and instead are for use within action blocks like `show`, `index`, etc.
2. Even for view logic, all methods from all `ViewHelpers` are merged into a single namespace, rather than separated into one namespace per resource.

I imagine that somewhere in the world, ActiveAdmin resources aren't always 200-300 line monsters. Thanks.

Comment: My recent answer to a similar question may be of interest to you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51548891/how-can-i-separate-activeadmin-controller-into-new-file/51559657#51559657

Comment: Thanks for the link @piers-c. That certainly answers how to wrap view logic and hints at a way towards wrapping business logic. Has there been any demand for a PR to reference a user-supplied subclass of ResourceController out there?